# Crystal Reports grouping two tables based on the primary key of one table

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 2 tables:

1. Product
   fields are:    prod_no (primary key), prod_name
2. Sales
   fields are:    sal_no, sal_date, cust, prod1 (foreign key i.e. prod_no), prod2 (foreign key i.e. prod_no), fst_qty, snd_qty

I want to sort my report based on prod_no.

Example:
Product

### prod_no  prod_name

```
 1.      printer

 2.      paper

 3.      cartridge
```

Sales

### sal_no sal_date customer prod1 prod2 fst_qty snd_qty

```
  1    5-sep-09   aaa        1      3      2        3

  2    5-sep-09   bbb        2      3      1        1

  3    5-sep-09   ccc        1      2      3        4
```

I want a report like this:

prod_no

1

### sal_no   sal_date   customer   qty

```
 1     5-sep-09    aaa        2
 3     5-sep-09    ccc        3
```

2

```
 2     5-sep-09    bbb        1
 3     5-sep-09    ccc        4
```

3

```
 1     5-sep-09    aaa        3
 2     5-sep-09    bbb        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Book - [Crystal reports 10: the complete reference By George Peck](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=eukKHY9wjAEC&pg=PA407&lpg=PA407&dq=Drill-Down+crystal+reports&source=bl&ots=O8BzgaRMLF&sig=JtSh8OCzUsZb5jyfeykxHD-udG0&hl=en&ei=tCGiStHaEMnBlAfktZH1CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8#v=onepage&q=Drill-Down%20crystal%20reports&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for subreports to me, with Prod_No passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on your grouping skills for this. I believe that if you simply create groupings for prod_no and then sal_no, and after placing the necessary fields in the proper group headers and details sections you should be able to display this info in the way that you want it.

Please see my answer on the below question for an example of a grouping similar to what you are looking for.

[How to avoid the duplicate values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264213/how-to-avoid-the-duplicate-values)

Hope this helps and don't forget to mark an answer as the accepted answer and vote for answers that have helped. Thanks