# Is that possible to bind two dataset at a same time in crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, dataset

Is that possible to bind two dataset at a same time in asp.net crystal report?

I tried the code below, but it asks for server details:

```
                Invoice inv = new Invoice();
                inv.OrgId = Session["org_id"].ToString();
                inv.InvoiceId = invoiceId.ToString();
                ds = _reportController.ReportPrintBillView(inv);
                dtBill=ds.Tables[0];
                dtInvoice = ds.Tables[1];

                ReportDocument myRpt = new ReportDocument();
                myRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("PrintandprintBill.rpt"));
                myRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("root", "root", "localhost", "hemaepdb");
                myRpt.SetDataSource(dtBill);
                myRpt.SetDataSource(dtInvoice);
                CrystalReportViewerPrint.ReportSource = myRpt;
                CrystalReportViewerPrint.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the report accepts one datasource. However your subreports may have a different datasource.

EDIT:

If you need data from two different datasets that have similar data you might try to combine the data into one dataset. Even if some of the data duplicates, you can then create groups and use the suppress functionality to only show and format the data in the way you need to see it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264213/how-to-avoid-the-duplicate-values) for a better explanation of the grouping and suppressing that I am referring to.

Comment: Mr Dusty:I have two dataset 
1.one for invoice info..it had only one row
2.second for list of bills ..have multiple rows.

how to bind these 2 dataset into CR

Comment: See the edit to my answer and let me know if you still have issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From ur Requirement i think u want to use View. View is one kind of logical table that maps other columns from different tables. And at Datable just use View Name and add this datatable to dataset. simply SetDataSource to dataset.